How to read all tables after a specific heading in a word document using?
I have a word document with multiple tables inside it but I only want to get the tables that comes after a specific heading named "Second heading"
This works to get any table I want but I'm not sure how to modify it to only get the tables after the above named heading
from docx import Document

doc = Document(templatePath)
table = doc.tables[0]

